# Why this inequality about exponential function is true?

Tags: analysis, inequality

I found someone uses the following inequality when $M>0$ is large enough:
$$(1-1/M)^M\ge 1/e - 1/M.$$
I am wondering why it is true?

Comment: $\lim_{m \to \infty} (1-1/M)^M = 1/e$

Comment: @UnbelieveTable But that does not prove the inequality.

Comment: @KaboMurphy You are right. I commented in case he and future readers didn't know. The posted answer looks legit for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take the log and use Taylor expansion
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\log\left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{M}\right)^M\right) &=& M \log(1 - \frac{1}{M})\cr &=& M\left(-\frac{1}{M}-\frac{1}{2M^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{M^2}\right)\right) \cr &=& -1 - \frac{1}{2M} + o\left(\frac{1}{M}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\log\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{M}\right) &=& -1 + \log(1 - \frac{e}{M})\cr &=& -1 - \frac{e}{M} + o\left(\frac{1}{M}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
\log\left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{M}\right)^M\right)
- \log\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{M}\right) =\left(e- \frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{M} + o\left(\frac{1}{M}\right) > 0
\end{equation}
when $M$ is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the same spirit as @Gribouillis, let
$$a_M=\left(1 - \frac{1}{M}\right)^M\implies \log(a_M)=M \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{M}\right)$$ So, by Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_M)=-1-\frac{1}{2 M}-\frac{1}{3 M^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{M^3}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor
$$a_M=e^{\log(a_M)}=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2 e M}-\frac{5}{24 e M^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{M^3}\right)=\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2 e M}+O\left(\frac{1}{M^2}\right)$$
$$a_M-(\frac 1 e-\frac 1 M) \sim \frac{2e-1}{2eM} > 0$$